# No matching creator found

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Recently I have made migration from mongosharp 1.8 to 2.0 .The only problem I have faced is aggregation with date fields.Let me show you how I construct query :

```
var aggregateResult = Items.Aggregate()
    .Group(
        g => new {
            // some fields
            Day = g.DateTime.DayOfYear
        },
        z => new {
            MyKey = z.Key
            // agrregation functions
        })
    .Project(
        d => new {
            // projection for other fields
            d.MyKey.Day
        });
```

I used [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Samples/AggregationSample.cs#L105) example from [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/#aggregation).

I got the following exception: `No matching creator found.` I have checked generated query and manually executed it - result was perfect. After reproducing test code and compare to my I find problem is in dates. So, can anyone point me to correct syntax/query rules  for dates? The generated query below proves that query is correct.

```
aggregate(
[
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "Day" : {
                    "$dayOfYear" : "$DateTime"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "Day" : "$_id.Day",
            "_id" : 0
        }
    }
])
```

**Workaround**

So, to make things work I do next workaround:

- create aggregate helper class which encapsulates access to database using Legacy assembly.
- implement methods which used queries constructed on bson documents
- inject it to my async 2.0 service and replace async calls with sync

Below is code to get collection and execute queries

```
_collection = new MongoDatabase(new MongoServer( MongoServerSettings.FromUrl(connectionString)), databaseName, new MongoDatabaseSettings()).GetCollection<MyClass>("collection_name"); 
var pipeline = new[] { match, groupBy, project, .... };
_collection.Aggregate(new AggregateArgs { Pipeline = pipeline }).ToList()
```

Comment: Could you add definition of `Items`?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin, Database.GetCollection<MyClass>("collection_name")  .... used as IMongoCollection<MyClass>

Comment: I'll reproduce your problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered this error today. Similar to the person asking the question, I had an anonymous type being populated from a mongo query.

The error seems to happen when the element you're fetching does not exist in database. In this case, mongo driver seems to get confused about what "type" the resulting anonymous type should be generated as.

I changed my anonymous type to a concrete type (by declaring a class for it) and that fixed the error.

Comment: Creating class solved same issue, my luck to find this answer, WOW

Comment: yes, this actually fixed my issue as well.

Comment: Enabling LINQ3 on v2.17 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 10):

For people using LINQ queries like myself, you could also consider using [coalesce expression (aka `??`)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/reference/driver/expressions/#ifnull) in `Select` to avoid having to create unnecessary concrete types.

*MongoDB.Driver 2.11.2 was used when writing below examples*

Consider this query:

```
var query = Collection
    .Where(x => filter.Inject())
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Title = x.Title // Some old entities do not have Title
    });
```

The query will be translated to `$project` like:

```
aggregate([{ "$project" : { "Title" : "$title" } }])
```

When some items do not have `$title`, the result cannot be mapped to anonymous type for the reason as per @r-j has stated, and the exception raises:

> No matching creator found.

If apply coalesce against `x.Title`:

```
new
{
    Title = x.Title ?? null
}
```

Then the query will be translated to:

```
aggregate([{ "$project" : { "Title" : { "$ifNull" : ["$title", null] } } }])
```

In which way a `Title` is guaranteed in the result.

The *downside* of this approach is the C# expression does look a bit confusing if look from C#'s perspective. If you enable nullable reference type and the `Title` property is not null in C#, you will see a warning/hint saying the left operand is never null.